# Asking a SPARQL query gives only the column names

Tags: sparql

I am a beginner in the Sparql queries. I have built a small ontology on Protege. Whenever I try to run a SPARQL query, it just gives the column names but not the actual answer. Here is the syntax for my query. Can anyone tell what is the issue there in the syntax?

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX ont: <http://www.semanticweb.org/izwan/ontologies/2022/10/SmallOntology>
SELECT  ?subject ?object
    WHERE { ?subject ont:MotherOf ?object}
```

A small depiction of the related classes is given in the picture below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWp68.png)

I tried to get those names where a person is a mother of another person.But it gives the column names as "subject" and "object" only.

Comment: Do you see your data when you run the query `SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o .}`?

Comment: yes I see it. Writing the followig query gives all of the subjects and objects.    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?subject ?object
 WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf ?object }

Comment: With that query, you find your classes (e.g., "Woman"), but not your data (e.g., the individual "Maryam"), right? Do you find individuals with my query? – And regarding your question: Do you want to find classes or individuals?

Comment: Yes I find all individuals with your query. But I want to find those individuals who are defined as the daughterOf some other individual.

Comment: the you have to use as predicate the property - and your prefix declaration of `ont:` is wrong, there should be a trailing `/` or `#` depending on whatever you used in Protege.

Comment: Can u plz explain the second sentence of yours?

Comment: `PREFIX ont: <http://www.semanticweb.org/izwan/ontologies/2022/10/SmallOntology>
` resolves the prefixed property `ont:MotherOf` to `http://www.semanticweb.org/izwan/ontologies/2022/10/SmallOntologyMotherOf` - you have to use `PREFIX ont: <http://www.semanticweb.org/izwan/ontologies/2022/10/SmallOntology/>` or `PREFIX ont: <http://www.semanticweb.org/izwan/ontologies/2022/10/SmallOntology#>` depending on what you specified in Protege, i.e. a trailing character is missing